# Remove .php from urls with htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

EDIT: current .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

## hide .php extension snippet

# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L]

# To internally forward /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

My site is hosted in a subfolder of a domain connected to a large hosting account.

```
basesite
  /iioengine
    /forums
      /.htaccess //file works
      /.... //other MyBB content
    /demos.php
    /index.php //iioengine.com (homepage)
    /.htaccess //file doesn't work
    /... //other iioengine php pages
```

Is the issue that I'm using two different htaccess files?

Here is a link that needs to work: http://iioengine.com/demos

I noticed that this current htaccess file disrupts all of the forums URL's as well

This no longer works: http://iioengine.com/forums/Forum-Box2D

EDIT: Thanks for reopening, I have made some progress. Here is my current htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
</IfModule>
```

I still get 404 pages, but if I put this line in:

`RewriteRule . /index.php [L]`

all non-'.php' requests get forwarded to the homepage... So mod_rewrite is definitely enabled, it's just not working right. Anyone know what the issue could be?

**EDIT**: This is **not a duplicate** - none of the other solutions work for me. My question is not *do solutions exist*, its *why aren't they working for me*. No one has been able to resolve this, I have been trying many solutions myself. Isn't the point of this forum to get solutions to specific issues?

Allow me to clarify...

I have MyBB running in a subfolder and its rewrites work fine. This link, for instance, works: http://iioengine.com/forums/Forum-Box2D

All the php pages that are not part of MyBB still have the .php extension in their URLs - I am trying to remove these but nothing is working. Example: http://iioengine.com/demos

... [original post]

There is obviously a lot of information out there about this, but I have tried almost a dozen different solutions and have not gotten past a 404 page.

Here is my site: http://iioengine.com/, all pages are php, and everything other than the homepage and all of the forums pages have a '.php' at the end of their URL that I would like to remove.

In addition to redirecting non-'.php' requests to the correct pages, I would also like to remove the '.php' part even when it is part of the request (because all of my content already specifies '.php' in its hyperlinks).

This is what I have so far, mostly taken from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9821222/remove-php-extension-explicitly-written-for-friendly-url), but it doesn't work, I get a 404 page.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.*).php$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %1 [L,QSA]
```

what do I need in my htaccess file to remove the file extension from the URL in all cases? Thanks

Comment: Maybe this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13832468/how-to-stop-htaccess-loop/13832827#13832827) helps. Check option II.

Comment: MVC, not that I know of. I tried option II - didn't work (still got 404 pages) and it messed up the formatting on all of my pages

Comment: I am sorry but I think this question won't be reopened because it is too localized, i. e. a solution for this question won't be helpful for others. StackOverflow is not a support organization, it is a QA site. Questions and answers are most helpful if they are helpful for a lot of people.

Comment: duh... they reopened it...

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Try this code for hiding .php (will work both ways):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

## don't touch /forum URIs
RewriteRule ^forums/ - [L,NC]

## hide .php extension snippet

# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L]

# To internally forward /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: I think there is an issue with how my htaccess file is being read or interpreted. This gives me a 404 page on each request

Comment: Pls post your latest .htaccess in your question. Also provide more details like what URI did you try and little bit info about your directory structure.

Comment: I think I know what's the problem and it can be fixed. Just need 1 more answer from you. What is DOCUMENT_ROOT for `http://iioengine.com/`  and where in DOCUMENT_ROOT you've placed above .htaccess file?

Comment: index.php and .htaccess are both in the iioengine folder, which is a direct subfolder of my hosting account's root

Comment: But I guess DOCUMENT_ROOT for `http://iioengine.com/` is iioengine folder isn't it? You can put `phpinfo();` in a php file to get that information.

Comment: yes it is. here's an info page if it helps iioengine.com/phpinfo.php - I need to remove the htaccess file for you to view it though

Comment: Ok got it, I edited my answer based on that `phpinfo()`. Put this edited code in the same .htacess and try it again.

Comment: It's definitely removing the extensions, but I'm still getting 404 pages everywhere - including the forums

Comment: Made another edit, pls try now. Also it would be better if we move this discussion to chat to sort this out.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28055/discussion-between-cbas-and-anubhava)

Comment: The previous example works very well when the url ends in a single .php file eg. http://mywebsite/file.php But, it removes everything else when I have additional parameters in the url e.g. http://mywebsite/file.php/param1. Does anyone know how to remove the .php extension, but keep or attach the other parameters? I would like something like http://mywebsite/file.php/param1 to become http://mywebsite/file/param1

Comment: @Sergio: That will require little different approach. Feel free to open a new question and post a link here. Its better not to edit this 2+ yrs old answer.

Answer (score 3):

try this.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

if this not work then your sever do not have mod_rewrite activated or support url rewriting.

Comment: is mod_rewrite on? check `phpinfo()`

Comment: I assume it is because the myBB htaccess rewrites work fine for all of the Forums pages.. ill use phpinfo to make sure

Comment: Here's the info page: http://iioengine.com/phpinfo.php. I can't see anything that specifies mod_rewrite

Comment: Still didn't work. I'll leave it up for about 20min. I'll look into my server capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
Options -Indexes +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine on

DirectoryIndex index.php

# REDIRECT Force requests for named index files to drop the index file filename, and force non-www to avoid redirect loop
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^/]*/)*index\.(html?|php[45]?)(\?[^\ ]*)?\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(([^/]*/)*)index\.(html?|php[45]?)$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^/]+)/([^\.]+)\.php\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([^.]+)\.php$ http://example.com/$1/$2 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^\.]+)\.php\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([^.]+)\.php$ http://example.com/$1/$2/$3 [R=301,L]

# REDIRECT www to non-wwww
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule .? http://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# REWRITE url to filepath
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([^/.]+)$ /$1/$2.php [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([^/.]+)$ /$1/$2/$3.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simplest syntax I have found, which would result as below:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?PrivacyPolicy$ legal.php?mode=privacy [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^Report/([0-9]+)$ report.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```

Results:

1. PrivacyPolicy to legal.php?mode=privacy
2. Report/55 to report.php?id=55

Answer (score 0):

On apache 2.4 and later, You can use the following Rule with **END** flag to remove .php extension from urls.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ /$1 [NC,L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)/?$ /$1.php [END]
```