# How to change permalink for php pages in localhost

Tags: php, wordpress, permalinks

I've seen that WordPress has a feature where you can change the permalink of your pages to different formats e.g. `www.example.com/index.html` to `www.example.com/index`.

How do you do that in localhost or in general any host without using WordPress for example if I have the page `www.example.com/about.php` I want it to be search in a browsers address bar as `www.example.com/about`

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: This may help you: http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15917258/remove-php-from-urls-with-htaccess

Comment: @HeroFTime That's not relevant because I am NOT using WordPress

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.htaccess`

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

The code above will get rid of the `.php` extension, thus giving you say `index` instead of `index.php`. And yes it works on `localhost` and nearly all hosting companies include it.

Comment: Where is the `.htaccess` file located in localhost? I can't seem to find it

Comment: Just create a plain text file and name it `.htaccess` and pop it into your root folder of your localhost server

Comment: what extension? `.txt`?

Comment: No. Just `.htaccess`. Thats what you name the file

Comment: I've got the `.htaccess` file working but where do I put the file? in the `www` directory?

Comment: If thats the root directory then yes. Where are your files located?

Comment: That is the root directory and all my files are there, I am getting this error when I try to open any of my files now:

`500 Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.`

Comment: Is `rewrite_module` enabled?

Comment: Oh, that's what it was... Thanks works now... but say if I use an online host for this... do I simply add that to the `.htaccess` file or would I have to mess with other things?

Comment: That's all you simply do with _most_ hosts. Theres probably only 1% of hosts that don't support it. Just pop it in, all you'll be good to go. If this was helpful marking it as answered and upvoting would be much appreciated.

Comment: Thanks, I don't have enough rep to upvote :p but when I do I sure will. :)

Comment: If I were to do the same for `.html` files then how would I do that?

Comment: Change the last line with `RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]`

Comment: I want it to happen for both `html` and `php` so do I just add that line?

Comment: Just rename then from `.html` to `.php`. Since HTML can be put into any PHP file. Then just use the line in my answer. I'm not home at the moment, but I find a way to get both of them if you must use HTML