# Manually mod_rewrite each page

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I tried everything on this world to make it work properly but it simply won't. I'm done with auto rewrite. You can still answer if you think you know what could be causing this but I doubt it's possible.

**Question:**
How would I go on **manually** `mod_rewrite` each page like so:

`domain.com/showthread.php?id=00` to `domain.com/showthread?id=00`

- It needs to work with different **thread ids**. It needs to work with
  other .php pages as well but I can manually add each to `.htaccess`
- It needs to redirect `/page` to `/page.php` but display `/page` in the url bar

(I have asked before ([Remove .php from URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29542588/remove-php-from-url)) how to automatically rewrite this but I just cannot get it to work properly and I'm running out on time and energy. and coffee.)

**Issue:**

Even though

```
<?php 
phpinfo();
```

Lists mod_rewrite as enabled

```
<?php
 if(!function_exists('apache_get_modules') ){ phpinfo(); exit; }
 $res = 'Module Unavailable';
 if(in_array('mod_rewrite',apache_get_modules())) 
 $res = 'Module Available';
?>
<html>
<head>
<body>
<p><?php echo apache_get_version(),"</p><p>mod_rewrite $res"; ?></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Displays "Module Available"

..it still does not function.

- `/page` and `/page/` return 404 in all cases
- `/page.php` works like normal without bar rewrite or does not function at all.

**I tried the following a.o.:**

```
(1)
# Apache Rewrite Rules
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options +FollowSymLinks
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /

# Add trailing slash to url
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/|#(.*))$
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1/ [R=301,L]

# Remove .php-extension from url
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
  RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)/$ $1.php 

# End of Apache Rewrite Rules
 </IfModule>
(2)
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
(3)
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
(4)
RewriteRule ^page$ page.php [L]
```

**Notes:**

- `sudo service apache2 restart` does not change anything.
- Server reboot changes nothing.
- I tried clearing other code inside, did not make any change.
- I cleared my browser cache 100 times

**ATTENTION:**

Please read the post before answering. I'm pretty sure this is not your average mod_rewrite issue.

Comment: Can confirm that this is not the case. `deny from all` also works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose your htaccess isn't working at all. Check in apache conf file for following

    ...
    AllowOverride None
    ...

and change it to AllowOverride All

Comment: Found that in /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
It was set to AllowOverride None
But it was also using the wrong directory /var/www/ without html/ which is the old apache dir.

None of my listed solutions worked properly though. I did it with http://stackoverflow.com/a/15940822/4191580

Works properly now

(My search function seems to not work, but I'm unsure if it's related)