# removing .php but now the folder structure doesn't work and trailing slash

Tags: php, .htaccess

I was to remove .php extension by using

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

but this introduced a problem which is i can't access to folder directories and their internal files and server is not even accepting trailing slash at the end.

so lets i visit this page

```
www.example.com/family
```

url will load fine

if i visit this page with / at the end

```
www.example.com/family/
```

note i have trailing slash / at the end, it won't work

now if i have a directory or folder name family

```
www.example/family
```

which is directory instead of my page then page will not work nor the directory or folder will be accessible.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15917258/remove-php-from-urls-with-htaccess

Answer (score 0):

Add a Rewrite Rule to Redirect to a URL with a slash:

```
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

Input URL: http://www.example.com/family

Output URL: http://www.example.com/family/

Comment: Infact i want server to accept the / slash at the end.

Comment: So what is your input and expected output URL?

Comment: input www.example.com/family
output www.example.com/family/

Comment: and also if there is internal directory of the same page named then it becomes a problem, page and the folder doesn't load up.

Comment: no , it didn't , it says : Object not found! and it changes the root url

Answer (score 0):

It seems like i was able to do it by using this code:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L]

# To internally forward /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

i am pasting here, if someone else searching for the same issue.