# How to hide .php extension in links from browser status bar

Tags: php, html, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am using an .htaccess file to hide the `.php` extensions in URLs. Although it is working fine, I now have to also hide the `.php` file extension in all the links that are shown on the page.

For example, when I hover the mouse over the link, its URL is showing the status bar and includes the `.php` extension.  How can I remove the `.php` from the link URLs too or completely hide the URL in the status bar of the browser?

I'm using the following code in my .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

## don't touch /forum URIs
RewriteRule ^forums/ - [L,NC]

## hide .php extension snippet

# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L]

# To internally forward /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]

# To remove www header
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [L,R=301]
```

<sup>(Code originally based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15917258/remove-php-from-urls-with-htaccess/15940822#15940822) by [anubhava](https://stackoverflow.com/users/548225/anubhava).)</sup>

The links in my HTML file look like `menu1.php`, `menu2.php`, etc. When I click on these links the URL shown in the browser URL bar looks like `domain.com/menu1`, which is good. But in the status bar, when I hover over these links, it still shows `menu1.php`.

How can I hide that `.php` suffix in the status bar? Do I have to manually change all the URLs in all the links, or there is some way I can hide them?

Comment: Not sure about this, but just remove the .php in <a href="">

Comment: Show the code or whatever where you output the hyperlinks.

Comment: yes, lets see code

Answer (score 4):

Short answer: **Yes, you do need to edit all your links to remove the `.php` extension from them.**

---

The .htaccess file you've quoted contains two (relevant) parts that do different things:

```
# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L]
```

This RewriteRule triggers when the user's browser requests an URL with a `.php` extension.  The rule causes the webserver to respond with an [external redirect](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/remapping.html#old-to-new-extern) to the same URL, but with the `.php` suffix removed.  The browser will then retry loading the page with the new URL, and will also show that new URL in the address bar.

```
# To internally forward /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

This second RewriteRule then triggers on URLs that *don't* include the `.php` extension, but which would correspond to actual `.php` files on your webserver if the extension was appended to them.  The rule then appends then `.php` extension back onto the URL and retries the request — but [it does so internally](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/remapping.html#old-to-new), inside your webserver, without the browser ever knowing about the change.

Thus, in effect, the browser is told to show the URL *without* the `.php` extension, but the webserver still ends up running the PHP script with the extension in place.

However, all this only happens *after* the user has clicked the link.  The URL rewrite rules in the .htaccess file do not, and cannot, magically edit your HTML code to fix the URLs included in them.  Therefore, to actually hide the fact that you're using PHP, you will need to manually edit your HTML (including any HTML code output by your PHP scripts themselves) to remove the `.php` filename extensions from the URLs.

(As a side effect, doing so also makes the first RewriteRule quoted above unnecessary.  However, you'll probably want to keep it anyway, so that any old links that still include the `.php` extension in the URL will still get automatically redirected.)

Comment: This should definitely have a lot more upvotes