# Apache RewriteRule infinite loop

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm working on rebuilding a link structure of a site.

For some parts the site now respond with actual php script like:

```
DOMAIN/about-us.php
```

I have to remap those kind of URLs like so (this is just an example):

```
DOMAIN/about-us.php --> DOMAIN/uk/about-us
```

Since those pages have been already indexed I'd like to use 301 redirects to the new resources.

I used those kind of rules:

```
RewriteRule ^/about-us.php$ /uk/company/about-us   [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^/uk/company/about-us$ about-us.php   [L]
```

but this hit an infinite loop.

I tried different solutions with no luck (I tried also this one: [How to stop .htaccess loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13832468/how-to-stop-htaccess-loop) - the second method suggested). The only thing that worked in my environment was to rename about-us.php and update the rule. But since we have a lot of scripts renaming all of those is not an optimal option.

Comment: Are all php files on the root folder? and u want it to work as /uk/company/about-us?

Comment: Hi Prix, most of the scripts are in the root folder. For the example above yes the url would be /uk/company/about-us which is non existent on the file system

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(.*)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f
RewriteRule /?([^/]+)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Will work only for the php's on the root folder.

Comment: Thanks Prix, I tried and it worked but below I'll write one more easy step to do the same thing.

Comment: This is the solution I came up with on my own


    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} !200
    RewriteRule ^about-us.php$ /uk/company/about-us   [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} !200
    RewriteRule ^contact-us.php$ /uk/company/contact-us   [R=301,L]

    RewriteRule ^uk/company/contact-us$ contact-us.php   [L]
    RewriteRule ^uk/company/about-us$ about-us.php   [L]

It seems to be working as expected.

Comment: @user2742557 don't see how that is less complicated when you're going to have to make it manually for every rule you have. [But if my solution worked for you, kindly mark it as the answer, see here how.](http://stackoverflow.com/about)

Comment: Your solution would work for the single situation I described. While my comment could be useful for different situations. BTW I can accept your answer.